# SPfx CKEditor 5 adding additional plugins

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, typescript

hopefully i'm not being too dense here. We have a requirement that a WebPart includes the CKEditor V5. But we need to implement some of the third party plugins that are listed on the CKEditor website.

**EDIT: [Removed initial code as it's no longer the approach that I'm taking]**

I've had some minor success in forking the CKEditor classic repo and using npm run build to then add it into the SPfx project as a single js file.

So the next step that I'm not sure of is adding the custom plugins into the CKEditor build. I'd like to add in [Simple Buttons](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/simplebutton). The CK documentations tate that we simple add an Import of it, and then amend the ClassicEditor.builtinPlugins array adding in the new plugin and then adding a button into the toolbar.

```
ClassicEditor.defaultConfig = {
    toolbar: {
        items: [
            'heading',
            '|',
            'bold',
            'italic',
            'link',
            'bulletedList',
            'numberedList',
            'imageUpload',
            'blockQuote',
            'insertTable',
            'mediaEmbed',
            'undo',
            'redo',
            'custombutton'
        ]
    },
    image: {
        toolbar: [
            'imageStyle:full',
            'imageStyle:side',
            '|',
            'imageTextAlternative'
        ]
    },
    table: {
        contentToolbar: [
            'tableColumn',
            'tableRow',
            'mergeTableCells'
        ]
    },
    // This value must be kept in sync with the language defined in webpack.config.js.
    language: 'en'
};
```

However I have no idea where the 'custombutton' is supposed to come from. I was hoping someone here might have implemented a custom CKEditor build in a webpart before and could lend some guidance. Thanks.

Comment: It would help if you provided the actual errors. Are they compile time errors?

Comment: @JoeMcShea I've just made an edit to my question as I've progressed a little further since asking.